# SSIS Migration - Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am working with SSIS packages and I have to migrate them to a newer instance of SQL Server.

When migrating and testing. I got this error:

`Data conversion failed while converting column "customer_id"(7) to column "customer_id_10(36). The data conversion for column "Produce" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.`

I am using visual studio 2019 and I migrated from version 3 dtsx package to version 8. And this error comes in a Data Conversion task connected between Flat File Input to OLE DB Destination

I tried changing the code page from 1252 to UTF-8 in the entire package but it did not work.

I suppose it is the length of the column but I am not sure yet.

Comment: The error is quite specific here; what about the error don't you understand so we can elaborate.

Comment: I am new at SSIS Packages. what I do not understand is if i must change the length or the code page destination.  In my Data Conversion task I have on left side **Input Column** (customer_id(. Then **Output Alias** (customer_id_10), **DataType** and **length** on 10". Finally codepage 1252

In the table destination is the same length.

Comment: It could be *either*. You need to inspect the data and your definitions for your column `customer_id`; we have no sample data and no definitions, so we don't know which it is and what you need to change.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether or not this error occurs in the unmigrated packages?

Comment: "I suppose it is the length of the column but I am not sure yet.". Is this because you're not sure how to check?

Comment: @Nick.Mc Not yet. this has happened when I tried to run a migrated package using VS 2019 to migrate

Comment: @Nick.Mc I checked the length of the column in the table destination and it is the same as the Data Conversion Task. I ran the dtsx package again after changing the code page from 1252 to 65001 (UTF-8) and it showed the next error:


The column "AMT" cannot be processed because more than one code page (1252 and 65001) are specified for it

Comment: and is the length of the data coming _into_ the data conversion task equal or smaller to the output length? Because the error could simply be because your data conversion is truncating data.

Comment: You can just hack away and try and resolve it that way but I think it's important to understand: why does this work in the unmigrated package? Are you certain you are using identical files etc.? Can you instead extend the data conversion step (and database table size) to say 50 characters